# Match price start and end with symbol sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to match all prices that  start and end with symbol

All I could do is this

```
\\$.[0-9].?.[0-9]?|.[0-9].?.[0-9]?\\$
```

by duplicating the expression

Is there better way to do it without duplicating the expression ?  more express means extra time

example

it will find

$12.5

12.5$

Note: the price between many words so you can't use  ^ and $

Comment: So are you trying to parse this regex in PHP or SQL? and which version of SQL are you using?

Comment: Sql  and SQL version  5.6.36-82

Comment: Please give examples of what you are trying to find and trying not to find.  Your question provides little guidance.

Comment: I added example in the question

Comment: How does "$12.5" start *and* end with a symbol?

Comment: What is the meaning of : **Note: the price in a comment**

Comment: in a comment, it means  you can't use ^ and $  since there are many words beside the price

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for strings that are composed of digits and start and end with `$`, I would go for:

```
where col regexp '^[$][0-9]*[.]?[0-9]*[$]$'
```

This will accept the single ".", but should otherwise work.

Comment: It won't work  since the price in a comment so it's not the first one!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in where condition

```
where column_name regexp '^[$][0-9]*[.]?[0-9]*$' OR column_name regexp '^[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]*[$]$';
```

in your where clause.

It will check for `$` at first position or `$` at last position.

Comment: This way it will be  slower than my solution since it will check for 2 regexs